# XP per hero level at Heroes of the Storm

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

How much XP one needs to level up a hero at Heroes of the Storm?

I found the answer [here](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/13778257884) only for 10 first levels:

```
1 => 2 : 100k
2 => 3 : 100k
3 => 4 : 100k
4 => 5 : 475k
5 => 6 : 475k
6 => 7 : 1,425m
7 => 8 : ~1.5m
8 => 9 : 2.85m 
9 => 10 : 4.75m
```

but now there are 20 levels. What are values for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Heroes of the Storm wiki](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Experience) matches my experience, which is a **further 4,750,000 XP** per level, all the way to level 20.

Comment: [This site](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Experience) confirms it